# Node.js Express Spotify API save in session

Tags: node.js, express, spotify, session-state

Question appeared while integrating Spotify API into Nodejs Express web application using `spotify-web-api-node`. How multiple simultaneous user requests should be handled? After passing the authentication step, user receives `access_token`, which is different for each user. Each request can have a session, for example using  `express-session` since `access_token` is unique for each authenticated user. The weird thing is that I can't find an example with proper session usage in the description and samples https://www.npmjs.com/package/spotify-web-api-node where `spotify-web-api-node` is used. How is that possible to use global variable without session? Would it make full mess among separate user requests or I'm missing something? I guess that the `access_token` would be always replaced with latest authenticated user. Another usage example is here https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node, though it also suggests to use one global instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to store the `access_token` and `refresh_token` after successful authentication in the session storage, than before calling Spotify API endpoints set both tokens for the current user from the present session:

saving tokens in the session after successful authentication:

```
app.get('/login', (req,res) => {
  var scopes = [ ... ]
  var authUrl = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes)
  res.redirect(authUrl+"&show_dialog=true")
})

app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query
  try {
    var data = await spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    const { access_token, refresh_token } = data.body
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token)
    spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refresh_token)

    req.session.spotifyAccount = { access_token, refresh_token }

    res.redirect('...')
  } catch(err) {
    res.send(`error ${err}`)
  }
});

app.get('/userinfo', async (req,res) => {
  try {
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(req.session.spotifyAccount["access_token"])
    spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(req.session.spotifyAccount["refresh_token"])
    var result = await spotifyApi.getMe()
    console.log(result.body);
    res.status(200).send(result.body)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err)
  }
});
```

since `access_token` is only identification key which identifies any API request, that ensures that API endpoints are called for the current user. This technique prevents mess and confusion, so that each user can see and manipulate his data only.